# How to get urls of users profiles by theirs login names in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Got this repository code.

```
public IEnumerable<FollowedPerson> ReadFollowedPersonsById(int id, SPList list)
{
    var item = list.GetItemById(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var likedByCollection = (SPFieldUserValueCollection)item["LikedBy"];
    if (likedByCollection == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var followers = new Collection<FollowedPerson>();
    foreach (var liker in likedByCollection)
    {
        followers.Add(new FollowedPerson
            {
                Name = liker.User.Name,
                ImageUrl = string.Empty //TODO Urls of users avatars
            });
    }
    return followers;
}
```

I want to get the collection of users that liked some list item. Collection item looks like this:

```
public class FollowedPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Getting their names works fine but I don`t know how I can get their avatar images by theirs login names.

```
liker.User //does not contain any url of user`s image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this info from user profile. You may read about how to work with it here: [Work with user profiles in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163800.aspx).
There is code snippet for retrieve all user profile properties:

```
// Replace the following placeholder values with the target SharePoint site and
// target user.
const string serverUrl = "http://serverName/";  
const string targetUser = "domainName\\userName";  

// Connect to the client context.
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(serverUrl);

// Get the PeopleManager object and then get the target user's properties.
PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(targetUser);

// Load the request and run it on the server.
// This example requests only the AccountName and UserProfileProperties
// properties of the personProperties object.
clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var property in personProperties.UserProfileProperties)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", 
         property.Key.ToString(), property.Value.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: but if I don`t have user account name? SPUser class only give me users Sid, LoginName and Id

Comment: @k.makarov, LoginName equals user accont name, isn't it?

Comment: I though it equals too. But at real login name and account name is not equal.

Comment: so I am trying to google this solution - get user profile image url using his login name from SPUser

Comment: @k.makarov, I think this may help: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/. In 2013 you have login name with auth provider info included (because of claims). You may convert it using code from article.